# How do I access the index of mysql_fetch_array from database in php?

Tags: php, indexing

I know how to fetch data using `mysql_fetch_array` and one variable will hold the data, but after fetching the data I want to access and print my desired index from the fetched data.

My current code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_select_db("htmlcontent", $con);

    $s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE place = 'luzon'");

    while($roww = mysql_fetch_assoc($s))
        {
        $pt2 = $roww['url'];
        echo "$pt2" ."<br>";

        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would print the value held by the `url` field in your `tags` table. 
You do not have to put `$pt2` within quotes, just use `echo $pt2 . "<br>";`

Also, I would recommend you use PDO or mysqli to make it work.

Comment: What you write is correct, but it's not an anwer to the question

Comment: i just want to print the index that i want to print. $pt2 holds all the fetched array but in a whole one. i cannot separate it in an index array. for example, i want to print the index 1. i should echo $pt2[1] but the only thing that prints is the second character. let say the $pt2 value is {joe,bob,john}, how do i print the index [1]? because it prints all the value using the mysql_fetch_array. i just want to print the bob, not all of them.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` fetches the data with column names as key, I suggest you use `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of the former as mysql_fetch_array() can accept both column names and number as the key.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** instead, (if you need array indexes too).

PS. I highly recommend you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead of mysql.